# Is there any static analysis tool for JS that will catch unhandled error events?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a static code analysis tool that would tell me that there are places in my code that don't handle possible error events?

I had an important script crash because I used `new WebSocket` without registering an `on('error')` - even though the place where the websocket was created was in a try/catch block. And I'd like to prevent similar situations again.

Comment: I do not think such a thing exists because it would have to have specific knowledge of how error handling works in every single library you use (promises, events, synchronous exceptions, etc...).  In this case, many errors are triggered via an event, but that just happens to be how this particular API (which is not even built into nodejs) works.  Other APIs work differently.  For example, the `got()` API or `fetch()` APIs are entirely promise-based and communicate their errors via rejected promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly answering your question about static analysis -- which always has limits -- but you can prevent crashes like this from bringing down your service by adding a catch-all:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.error(`**** Caught exception: ${err}:`, err.stack);
});
```

Clearly, you should try hard *not* to rely on this, because the code blocks where such exceptions are thrown will not complete as intended. But it's a useful safe-guard to have to avoid downtime.

Comment: It's not entirely clear that just using this and then pretending that nothing bad actually happened and letting your server just continue to run is a good thing.  Unhandled exceptions can leave resources (such as file handles or database connections) in a bad state or cause memory or resource leaks.

Comment: Thanks. This is better than nothing. In my case a script needs to run at a specific time of a specific day, so if it crashes and is restarted by nodemon/pm2/docker that a catastrophe of much higher proportions than anything that happens to the server it's running on.